# Need to get the path from an image inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I am developing an app that takes some photos, and stores it in the device's SD, in a given folder.

Later, that images are presented inside a LinearLayout (Horizontal) inside a ScrollView. I need a way to delete an image from the SD folder if the user does long click it. This is my code:

After taking photo, inside onActivityResult, I call this method:

```
public void updatePhotos(){
    hScrollView.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout lLayout=new LinearLayout(ctx);
    lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    hScrollView.addView(lLayout);
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
        lLayout.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
}

public View insertPhoto(String path){
    Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(path, 220, 220);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            //LongClick logic here


            return false;
        }
    });

    layout.addView(imageView);
    return layout;
}
```

How could a achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: It's better you choose an ListView instead of LinearLayout. It's easy to get the position from an adapter or an array with a ListView. 
Doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html
Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tags for this case:

```
 public View insertPhoto(String path){
        Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(path, 220, 220);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setTag(path);
        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                //LongClick logic here
                  System.out.println(v.getTag())
                  File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  + v.getTag());
                  if(file.exists()) file.delete();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Solve your problem?

Comment: I was about to add an answer with that very same solution (I found it after some research), but you got ahead :) Thanks Fabio.